# How to include card widget with image into Dismissible widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

I've created a list of card widget(which has image and text widget). When I try to wrap the card widget inside the Dismissable widget, the UI collapses.

how to make the card's width fill the screen?

Below is code snippet the single card widget

```
class ProductCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductCardWidget(
      {super.key, required this.index, required this.products});
  final List products;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        elevation: 10,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            // final productDetails = ProductModel(productId: products[index]['id'], productTitle: products[index]['title'], productImage: products[index]['image'], productDesc: products[index]['description'], productSpecs: products[index]['specification']);
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (ctx) => ProductViewerScreen(
                          productDetails: products[index],
                        )));
          },
          splashColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 155, 190, 255),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Image.asset(
                products[index].productImage,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(products[index].productTitle),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the snippet where I try to wrap the above card widget with Dismissable widget (inside a listview)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget card_widget;

  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        card_widget = ProductCardWidget(index: index, products: products);
        if (isFavoriteList) {
          card_widget = Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              background: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                allProductDetails[products[index].productId]['is_favorite'] =
                    false;
                favorites.remove(products[index]);
              },
              child: ProductCardWidget(index: index, products: products));
        }

        return card_widget;
      });
}
```

The final UI I got

[overall look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E8dj.png)

[while dismissing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTtYB.png)